# How to model data series with constant expected value and varying periods of high and low volatility

Tags: time-series, variance, arima

I have a data series that has a constant mean an a volatility that switches among periods of high volatility and periods of low volatility?
What do you suggest to model this data series?
An AR model simply gives a straight line, that is, the intercept term is equal to the mean and the coefficients of the lag terms are practically zero.
Data series looks like this:

[image]

Comment: If your data exhibits varying volatility, maybe a GARCH model or a stochastic volatility model may be appropriate? But you really should test for heteroscedasity (?) first

Answer (score 0):

Data plots suggesting non-constant error process can often be treated by intervention detection schemes which identify deterministic structure and possible ARIMA structure which might otherwise be obfuscated. Detecting non-homogeneous error variance can follow yielding either the need for decoupling the expected  value and local variance OR actually finding break-points in error variance. Please post your data and I might be able to help further.